# Record voice with ASP.NET?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-3.5, audio-recording, voice-recording

How can I record voice from an ASP.NET application and upload to server? Is it possible to do using AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to record audio in a web browser with plain old JavaScript and HTML (including ASP.NET or any other server-side language or platform). You would think it would be possible using Flash, [but it is not possible, at least not yet](http://bkendall.biz/2009/05/recording-web-audio/). The closest thing I have found is a [Java applet for recording sound](http://www.javasonics.com/).

Comment: Recording audio with Flash is certainly possible, because there flash voice/video chat services.

Comment: I should qualify that: it is not currently possible to record audio in the flash client without using special server software. Please see http://www.getmicrophone.com/ for details.